# How to center an inline sub-menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to center my sub-menu for my bootstrap 3 navbar.

This is my desired outcome:
[A picture of what the menu is suppose to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhIZk.png)

However, my sub-menu floats to the left.

The HTML:

```
<li id="menu-item-243" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-243 dropdown submenu"><a href="#">Pages<span></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-241" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-241"><a href="http://thenordik.com/demo/themeforest/wordpress/specialists/about-team/">About Team</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-244" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-244"><a href="http://thenordik.com/demo/themeforest/wordpress/specialists/404">404</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-inline .nav .dropdown-menu {
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #d5c298;
    color:#fff;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav-inline .nav .dropdown-menu li {
  float: left;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-inline .nav .dropdown-menu li {
    float: none;
  }
}
.nav-inline .nav .dropdown-menu li a {
  width: auto !important;
  background: transparent;
  line-height: 49px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-inline .nav .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

The codepen is https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdNZWL

Comment: _“However, my sub-menu floats to the left”_ - well that’s what `float` does ... Don’t use float, but inline-block or flexbox then.

Comment: @CBroe I have used inline-block and it does not work.

Comment: Then you have most likely not bothered to do the most basic of research to find out _how_ to center inline-block elements ...

Comment: @CBroe why are you so passive aggressive? Are you alright? I am just a beginner just trying to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Centering stuff with CSS in all possible ways and nearly every constellation imaginable is a topic that has been discussed to death multiple times over already on the whole internet. I have a hard time believing that anyone could fail to find anything helpful on the matter, if they actually made a serious effort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add:

```
    .navbar-links-custom .dropdown ul {
         text-align:center;
     }

     .navbar-links-custom .dropdown ul li {
         float: none;
         display:inline-block;
     }
```

In case that something of these is not working, try adding !important after the value.